# Is there a Java EE filter for wrapping and modifying responses?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I want to wrap and modify the response to an HTTP request to my Java EE/tomcat application. That is, I have a number of Struts 2 actions that generate results, and I'd like to put a front end on them that modifies the response to do things like hide links, etc. Modifying each of the sources is out of the question because of the large number and variety of them.

I know I can write a Servlet Filter that does what I want, but I'd like to build on a standard, well-tested solution rather than re-inventing the wheel. I've searched for one, and there are places in the Java EE docs that describe such a beast, but have not been able to find one that I can download.

**Edit**: There are comments that this is a terrible idea. I'm open to suggestions as to a better one. The situation is that I have a large number of actions out there, written over a long period of time, and there are various systemic modifications that I'd like to do to their output. I don't want to modify all the actions because that violates DRY (and would be a ton of work). It seems to me that this is exactly what filters are made for - essentially AOP for HTTP responses. Am I thinking wrong?

**Edit #2**: As to the significance of the change, it's hard to say. It's generally not significant in the sense of adding a lot of new content to the page. It's more scanning the response and making relatively small changes: for example, adding classes to links under certain conditions, injecting small bits of code in various places on the page, or (in the extreme case) clipping out a div that should not appear to the user. I would say the biggest issue is that the system consists of approximately 4000 unique pages, each generated by a separate action and/or view using several different technologies. We can say this system structure stinks, but that's the reality of life working on a very large, 15 year old piece of software. My other idea is to only implement a filter to do the *scanning*, and inject modifications in javascript. This does not help in a situation that is truly security-related (i.e. don't want to let the user even see the content), but it might help in a number of other cases that are done primarily for user convenience. Thanks everybody for the discussion, please keep it coming.

Comment: So you want to parse the response, modify the DOM, and send it back? Yuck.

Comment: Maybe if you gave some more details about the exact work you need to do. Is the change actually a significant change, which you would reasonably expect to be a lot of work (and using a servlet filter would clearly be a hack) ? Or is the existing code, not very well structured so what should be a small change, is actually big and risky?

Comment: I edited my text to incorporate your questions. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry, I never replied. Rick Mangi below sums it up well. What you are proposing sounds nasty, but if you have to make those changes and the code-base working with isn't very good, it certainly is a way to do it. But be aware it is a hack, which will make later maintenence ever harder. At some point, you have to bit the bullet and fix the underlying code (or throw it away :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your changes can be classified, I recommend using jQuery.
All you have to do is to add jQuery to your page, select your tags according to your conditions, and then apply what you need to them.

If you have a layout manager (I believe you must have SiteMesh or Tiles if it is a Struts 2 application), you can just add what you need in your layout templates, and everything will be ok.

---

Another solution which comes to my mind is applyable if you have used consistent tag libraries inside your project. For example if you have used `<xyz:myLink/>` tag all your project, (even if they are Strtus2 standard tags, or ....), you can just re-implement your tags, and then assign them to old names in TLD files.

I believe a combination of my previous solution (jQuery) and this solution (reimplementing tags) could help you much, and it would be much easier and more perform than parsing the result DOM and recreating it again.

---

And one another solution, if your result pages are XHTML (well formed XML), you can use an XSLT transformer to transform your XHTML to another XHTML.

Comment: Amir - I'm not sure what you mean. If I am doing something wrong, I promise it's not intentional. Should I be doing something different than I am?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a really horrible idea, but take a look at urlrewrite filter http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ which lets you do pretty much anything you want. You might also look at http://www.sitemesh.org/

Comment: I am familiar with the URL rewrite filter, but I thought that was essentially mod_rewrite for java and, as such, didn't have support for modifying results (only URIs).

Comment: If you have to parse the output from your servlets *at all* then I would reconsider the filter idea. The performance overhead will make the UX suck. If what you're doing is simpler than that then go ahead. I would consider making a little helper library to do what you need and using it in all the servlets/actions that need it.

Comment: URL Rewrite Filter will let you do anything you want with a request that matches a regexp, or even ANY request. You could absolutely use it to run anything you want against a request on its way in/out of your servlet stack. I don't think what you're looking to do is good design at all, but if that's your requirement, this is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a difficult to maintain system. It's time to harden up and start dealing with the problem, as best you can, from the core. Figure out an architecture you'd like to have and then start moving slowly towards that. Trying to fix things with a filter on top makes the maintainability worse and the cost to your organisation higher.